# Casperjs checking if xpath exists or not

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

okay can somebody help me i am new to casperjs and so far stackoverflow has been amazing the people here are very helpful.

after finally getting my script working and making it echo the html i want to add a new function and need help on how i would do it.

basically instead of echo'ing the html out.

i would like to check to see if an xpath exists if it does i want it to echo

```
you still have minutes
```

and if it does not exists echo

```
no minutes left
```

here is the xpath i want to check

```
 /html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

can anybody show me a simple function that can do this

my function

```
// Wait 2 sec then write to txt file
casper.wait(9000, function() {
//this.echo(this.getHTML());
//this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
'username': 'test',
'password': 'test'
}, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so instead of xpath i reverted to css selector heres how i solved my problem

```
 if (this.exists('div.box_pink div.inner p')) {
 this.echo('the css selector exists'); } else { 
 this.echo('the css selector dont exist'); 
 } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I revised based on the code you provided.

```
casper.start('http://yoursite.tld/', function() {
    // Wait 2 sec then write to txt file
    this.wait(9000, function() {
        //this.echo(this.getHTML());
        //this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        this.fill('form[name="LoginForm"]', {
            'username': 'test',
            'password': 'test'
        }, true);

        if(this.exists('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')) {
            console.log('you still have minutes');
        }
        else {
            console.log('no minutes left');
        }
    });

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but i am really struggling to get it to worki within my script any chance you can show a way off adding it to my fill form example i will put it in my post above

Comment: jason check out the function in my post thanks again